# Why command gsort doesn't order right?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, compare, stata

I'm trying to translate a command from Stata to R, but comparing the result between the two commands I realized that some lines are not perfectly in order. Does anyone know how to make the two commands perfectly equal?

```
Stata code with reproducible example:
clear
input str32 dest12010 byte uf_amc exist_d2010 str32 final_name 
dest12010 uf_amc exist_d2010 final_name
"LAGO DA PEDRA" 3 1 "LAGO DA PEDRA"
"LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO" 3 1 "LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO" 
"LAGO DO JUNCO" 3 1 "LAGO DO JUNCO" 
"LAGO VERDE" 3 1 "LAGO VERDE" 
"LIMA CAMPOS" 3 1 "LIMA CAMPOS" 
"LORETO" 3 1 "LORETO"
end

gsort uf_amc dest12010 -exist_d2010 final_name
```

```
R code with reproducible example:
example <- structure(list(dest12010 = c("LAGO DA PEDRA", "LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO", 
"LAGO DO JUNCO", "LAGO VERDE", "LIMA CAMPOS", "LORETO"), uf_amc = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), exist_d2010 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    final_name = c("LAGO DA PEDRA", "LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO", 
    "LAGO DO JUNCO", "LAGO VERDE", "LIMA CAMPOS", "LORETO")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

dplyr::arrange(example, uf_amc,dest12010,(exist_d2010),final_name)
```

Output

[image: Output]

Columns with "_s" at the end are the result of Stata using `gsort` and without this detail it is the result of R `arrange`.

Comment: We need to see raw data, not an image. How do we know whether the `dest12010` variable in Stata is a string variable or a numeric variable with value labels? On the evidence of the image  only the destination columns look problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your example. But in that `uf_amc` and `exist` are constant and thus irrelevant and the two string variables are equal to each other. Thus your command is equivalent in Stata to `sort dest12010` which yields the order `"LAGO DA PEDRA"' "LAGO DO JUNCO" "LAGO VERDE" "LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO" "LIMA CAMPOS" "LORETO"` which seems correct to me; the only detail to explain is that spaces sort before letter `A`.  Thus the Stata sort order implied by your image is not reproducible. I've not tried your R code, which looks not reproducible to me given the use of `example` and `exaple`.

Comment: The only guess I have is that you have in your real data a mix of different space characters, in Stata terms `uchar(32)` and `uchar(160)`. I see no case for re-opening this.

Comment: There is a spurious single quotation mark in my first comment today, which is to do with my editing and nothing to do with Stata's results. ,

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you for responding. I have to translate a big chunk of code from stata to R and I'm not familiar with stata language. I wasn't aware that in gsort space was importante. This is my original line of code it's in a loop :  `gsort uf_amc dest1y0 -exist_dy0 final_name `  can I make it ignore space? Or how can I adopt it to sort? Ps: for this example, i'm using y0 as 2010 (part of loop)

Comment: `gsort` and `sort` don't behave differently in this respect: if you ask to sort a string, in principle every character is relevant. If you want spaces to be ignored, you need to sort on a version of the variable in which they are removed; or to parse the string into words (using `split`) and sort on the words jointly.

Answer (score 1):

What R does I happily leave to those who use it routinely.

The complaint here is that Stata is behaving at least in a puzzling way, and at most incorrectly. This complaint cannot be supported given the supposedly reproducible example.

First, let's clear away some distractions in the example. The two string variables are identical, at least when I copy and paste them from here, and compare their values. The two numeric variables are constant in what is given, so how they sort doesn't affect the example. Further, `gsort` is a wrapper for `sort` and does not behave differently unless a minus sign flags reversing the default order, which isn't specified for the variable in question. Finally, there is a spurious extra line, which is edited out of what is below.

Code first, then code with results:

```
clear
input str32 dest12010 byte uf_amc exist_d2010 str32 final_name 
"LAGO DA PEDRA" 3 1 "LAGO DA PEDRA"
"LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO" 3 1 "LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO" 
"LAGO DO JUNCO" 3 1 "LAGO DO JUNCO" 
"LAGO VERDE" 3 1 "LAGO VERDE" 
"LIMA CAMPOS" 3 1 "LIMA CAMPOS" 
"LORETO" 3 1 "LORETO"
end

assert dest12010 == final_name 
keep dest12010 
sort dest12010 

list , sep(0)

gen dest12010_2 = subinstr(dest12010, " ", "", .) 

sort dest12010_2 

list , sep(0)
```

Results

```
. assert dest12010 == final_name 

. keep dest12010 

. sort dest12010 

. list , sep(0)

     +--------------------------+
     |                dest12010 |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |            LAGO DA PEDRA |
  2. |            LAGO DO JUNCO |
  3. |               LAGO VERDE |
  4. | LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO |
  5. |              LIMA CAMPOS |
  6. |                   LORETO |
     +--------------------------+

. gen dest12010_2 = subinstr(dest12010, " ", "", .) 

. sort dest12010_2 

. list , sep(0)

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     |                dest12010             dest12010_2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. | LAGOA GRANDE DO MARANHAO   LAGOAGRANDEDOMARANHAO |
  2. |            LAGO DA PEDRA             LAGODAPEDRA |
  3. |            LAGO DO JUNCO             LAGODOJUNCO |
  4. |               LAGO VERDE               LAGOVERDE |
  5. |              LIMA CAMPOS              LIMACAMPOS |
  6. |                   LORETO                  LORETO |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Key points:

1. The `assert` statement checks that the two string variables are identical. If it failed, the script would stop. If the assertion is correct, all proceeds.
2. A `sort` on the variable yields the result shown. The only detail that might need explanation is that spaces are characters too and not ignored. `sort` is entirely mechanical and oblivious of meanings. In particular, spaces `" "` sort before `"A"`.
3. If a `sort` that ignores the spaces is wanted, then the easiest solution is to remove the spaces before `sort`ing.

If R works differently, so be it, but that would seem to raise the question of what is wanted.